# Swift - use of unresolved identifier NSExpression

Tags: swift, nsexpression

I tried the below code on https://iswift.org/playground, but it says `use of unresolved identifier NSExpression`. Please let me know if I am missing something.

```
var numericExpression = "4 + 3 - 2"    
let expression = NSExpression(format: numericExpression)     
var result = expression.expressionValueWithObject(nil, context:nil)    
return result
```

Comment: Did you import Foundation.

Comment: Yes i tried. It says import is not allowed in sandbox

Comment: Not related to your issue but Swift 3 or later should be `expression.expressionValue(with: nil, context: nil)`